How to speed up the operation of repeatedly filter and create columns with filtered values?
The task is to filter a polars dataframe df with a lot of conditions, create columns of values of for each condition, and then concat all the sub_df among all conditions.
import polars as pl
from itertools import product

df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [31,32,73,24,15,26,57,98,79,10], 
                   "B": [11,22,53,44,53,16,27,38,49,10], 
                   "C": [41,12,23,44,25,46,27,48,29,10], 
                   "D": [71,52,13,34,53,36,27,48,39,10], 
                   "E": [81,82,63,24,15,56,47,68,49,10]})

a12_l = [[13,16], [12,72], [18,22]]
b12_l = [[11,13], [14,55], [22,55]]
c12_l = [[23,76], [13,65], [23,56]]
d12_l = [[21,42], [18,25], [25,35]]

pl.concat([df.filter((pl.col('A').is_between(a1,a2)) & (pl.col('B').is_between(b1,b2)) & 
                     (pl.col('C').is_between(c1,c2)) & (pl.col('D').is_between(d1,d2))).\
              with_columns(a1=a1, a2=a2, b1=b1, b2=b2, c1=c1, c2=c2, d1=d1, d2=d2) 
              for [a1, a2], [b1, b2], [c1, c2], [d1, d2] in product(a12_l, b12_l, c12_l, d12_l)])

the df has millions of rows and the combination of filters is up to 200000, so the whole process is quite slow.

"The task is to [...] and then concat all the sub_df" - So if do it without that, I'd be failing the task?

How many rows does the result have?

the output rows would depends on how may combination of filters applied. each filter would result in around 100 rows of output.  And without cancat all the sub_df is probably okay.

Polars can parallelize queries if you use lazyframes and collect_all, e.g. lf = df.lazy() and pl.concat(pl.collect_all([lf.filter(...) for ...])) but it's not clear how much it would help here.

You can calculate every compare and save the results in a DataFrame, and then use all_horizontal() to calculate the logic and:
import polars as pl
from itertools import product, chain
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

n = 50
df = pl.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, n)), schema=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

a12_l = [[13,16], [12,72], [18,22], [80, 90]]
b12_l = [[11,13], [14,55], [22,55], [70, 80]]
c12_l = [[23,76], [13,65], [23,56], [60, 80]]
d12_l = [[21,42], [18,25], [25,35], [50, 60]]

conditions = [a12_l, b12_l, c12_l, d12_l]

dfs = pl.concat([
    df.select(pl.col(c).is_between(vmin, vmax).alias(f'{c}{i}') for i, (vmin, vmax) in enumerate(ranges))
        for c, ranges in zip(df.columns, conditions)
], how='horizontal')

exprs_index = []
for idx in product(*[range(len(c)) for c in conditions]):
    expr = pl.all_horizontal([f"{c}{i}" for c, i in zip(df.columns, idx)]).arg_true().implode()
    exprs_index.append(expr)

df_ranges = pl.DataFrame(
    [list(chain.from_iterable(cond)) for cond in product(*conditions)],
    orient='row',
    schema=chain.from_iterable([[f'{c.lower()}1', f'{c.lower()}2'] for c in df.columns])
)        

row_index = pl.concat(
    [dfs.select(pl.concat(exprs_index).alias('index')), df_ranges], how='horizontal'
).filter(pl.col('index').list.len() > 0).explode('index')

df2 = df.with_row_index().join(row_index, how='right', on='index').drop('index')


this method reduces running time from 300 sec to 13 sec for a quick test. Thanks a lot!
